# How do I get all email addresses that replied to my email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using the web browser version of Microsoft Outlook.

I emailed 10 recipients, putting all their email addresses in the BCC field. They all replied to me. I want to download all the email addresses that replied to me. How do I do that?

Comment: Use a mail client of your choice that supports IMAP

Comment: What have you tried? They replied to you so you look at the replies and get the email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, it’s impossible to directly export the email addresses in OWA .

You can right click the user name and copy the email addresses.
[image]

Here's a similar thread for your reference.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/exporting-work-emails-from-outlook-web-app/62029e6f-6321-4f4f-ba87-8653d4597931

Comment: How's everything going now?